# How to install CLI11?

Tags: cmake

I use the [5th method](https://github.com/CLIUtils/CLI11/blob/master/README.md#install) to install [CLI11](https://github.com/CLIUtils/CLI11).

I test the [`../CLI11/test_package`](https://github.com/CLIUtils/CLI11/tree/master/test_package) and want to use `find_package` to include `CLI11` but failed.

The content of CMakeLists.txt.

```
project(PackageTest CXX)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

find_package(CLI11 CONFIG REQUIRED)
...
```

I got the error as follow:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "CLI11" with any of
  the following names:

    CLI11Config.cmake
    cli11-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "CLI11" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "CLI11_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "CLI11"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
...
```

Comment: Documentation is... misleading. You do not use `find_package` to install the library, you use to use the library. You have to install it first. So as the link says, do `configuring and installing the project is required for linking CLI11 to your project in the same way as you would do with any other external library`. _After_ that you can use `find_package` to _use_ the library in your project.

Comment: I used the following command to install.  
`mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
GTEST_COLOR=1 CTEST_OUTPUT_ON_FAILURE=1 make test`
But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make -j
sudo make install
```

The last `sudo make install` will copy files into the `/usr/local/include` folder.